# how to verify plain text key vs hashed API key

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A user can generate an API key by pressing a button, and I save the API key in the database. However, I don't save it as plain text, but rather hash it. I thought this was wise until I started trying to verify the API key.

I am hashing like this:

```
const saltRounds = 10;
const key = crypto.randomUUID();
const hashedToken = await bcrypt.hash(key, saltRounds);
```

The problem now is that in the other application, the user doesn't send any user details like email address for example. So, if they had I could have done a `findOne({email: email})` or if there was a user ID I could have done `findById` etc. but now only the API key is sent.

So, I am receiving the plain text version of the API key and need to somehow compare it.

I would have done the below but I don't actually have `user.apiKey`.

```
const validKey = await bcrypt.compare(key, user.apiKey);
```

So, if all I have is the plain text API key, how can I find it and compare it in the database?

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely hash your API keys. In effect, they are your passwords and should be treated as such. What you need to include in the database is to add a column for user_id against hashed API_KEY column. When API key is sent in the request you look for hashed value of API_KEY in database and find user against it. But if you want the request to be Authenticated and Authorized, then you will have to ask client to send some auth identified like cookie or token.

Comment: @heyitsvajid thanks for your response. How do WordPress plugins do it for example when there is no user ID? For example if you install a mailchimp plugin, it simply asks for the API key and no user ID. Does this mean that mail chimp is storing its API keys in plain text as that is easier to look up without some sort of ID as you are just looking for a plain text match of the API key.

Comment: @heyitsvajid How would you look for the hashed api key in the database if all you have is the plain unhashed apikey. To compare it to the hashed key, you would need to know also the salt used for hashing ...

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution but not sure if it is any good. Basically what I ended up doing is creating a prefix for the api key and concatenating it with the actual API key.

`const concatKey = keyPrefix + "." + token;`

So, I save `keyPrefix` in the database and use that as the unique ID. I also  save a hash of `concatKey`.

Then when I send requests to the API, I split the api key and get the prefix before the `.` and look that up in the database ie: the unique identifier. I then compare the hashes and if all okay the request can proceed.

It's not pretty, but it works.